# How to get mousewheel to work on a DataGridView table?

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView table that has quite a bit on entries. I was wondering if there's anyway I can get the Mousewheel able to scroll through the table?

Comment: if you're focused on the datagridview and move the mousewheel, it should already natively scroll the dgv...but if you want to do that manually for whatever reason, there's an example of how to do that [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630635-Scrolling-datagridview-using-the-mousewheel)

Comment: [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/002aaa37-2a71-44ed-95e9-5352b1eb2f64/mouse-wheel-on-vbnet-2010-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols) might be useful too

Comment: The normal behavior is for it to scroll if it is the active control.  Depending on your OS there are mouse fixer/drivers which will scroll things that the mouse is over even if it is not the active control or window